# Protecting private key generated for AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, cryptography, private-key

As far as I know, EC2 instance use a public/private cryptography. 
I have on my ~/.ssh local folder a pem file that hold the private key. And on remote server on ~/.ssh/authorized_keys that store the public key.
Am I right?

And the question is, how do I protect my private key, i.e., the pem file.

Comment: By protect means what do you mean exactly?

Comment: @ArtjomB. I think he says his private key is stored locally and the public key is on the instance (as it should be).

Comment: @jbird If that is the case, then this has nothing to do with EC2, does it?

Comment: @ArtjomB. Not really - except he did ask if that is correct (which it is). Otherwise it is a general question about how to protect a private key.

Comment: @jbird
You are ritght. I have the private key on my local machine.

Comment: @jbird: I think it is a more general question. How do I protect my private key?

Comment: Some tips are given in the AWS Security Best Practice guide (http://media.amazonwebservices.com/AWS_Security_Best_Practices.pdf). The whole document is a really good read for AWS security best practices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure it has a passphrase - never a blank one.  Never commit it to a code repository.  Never email it, or otherwise disclose it. Keep a copy secured physically in a different location.

Use the PKCS#8 private key format. [From Improving the security of your SSH private key files](https://martin.kleppmann.com/2013/05/24/improving-security-of-ssh-private-keys.html)

> If you already have a strong passphrase on your SSH private key, then
>   converting it from the traditional private key format to PKCS#8 is
>   roughly comparable to adding two extra keystrokes to your passphrase,
>   for free. And if you have a weak passphrase, you can take your private
>   key protection from “easily breakable” to “slightly harder to break”.

Comment: But by default, the private key that aws generates has no passphrase.

Comment: Yes, that is insecure. Generate your own and import it.

Comment: Is there anyway to add the pem file to ssh-add permanently? is it a good ideia?

Comment: Yes, if the key has a pass phrase it is. I use pagent in windows, that provides the same function to SSH

Comment: If I add my file permanently to ssh-agent, Can I delete my private key?

Comment: No, the agent is only a convenience tool, it provides your passphrase when requested.  You would still want a copy of the key, if only for backup.